# Overriding Appbarbutton brushes wp8.1 (Winrt) not working

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I try to override AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush in my App.xaml to change the highlight color when pressing on icon in the appbar. I do not understand why this is not working. I thought in WP 8.1 it is possible, but no color overriding nor applying any custom style is helping. It will be all completly ignored. In WP 8 at least I could override the accent color, but this is no more possible, or I do not know how.

Does anybody can help me?
It would be great.

bye
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot override the colours on individual AppBarButtons in the AppBar on Windows Phone. You can set the foreground and background colours of the AppBar itself and that will reflect in the AppBarButtons.

Comment: Thank you! But by the way is it possible to change the system accent color for one application like in WP8 with ThemManager? I see the Advantages from the internal themes, but now I have to override every accent color from every control I am using. With changing the accent it would be more easy.

Comment: @Rob why is this the case? Other UI controls honor the theme resources correctly and can be overridden, what makes the AppBarButton so special?